# ERP Integration, Bulk Import Products , Date Invalid Error

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, error

I have the following Problem, I am trying to create a small ERP System between SQL Management System and Magento, so I have created a tool that reads from the SQL DB and create XML Format Result, then I created a Function which Reads this XML Format in order to insert the result into the MAGENTO DB, it worked Perfectly Locally where all the Product Items were either being inserted or updated, 
but When I tried to use it on the Actual Server it kept on saying "INVALID DATE", without specifying what is the INVALID Date and why!!!

Is it something related to my SERVER Configuration? or should I update the created At and Updated At Fields?

Below is the Function that I am using to Insert New Products

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productModel
                //->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
                ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
                ->setAttributeSetId(4) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
                ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
                ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
                //->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
                ->setSku($item->No_) //SKU
                ->setReference_code($item->No_) //SKU
                ->setName($item->description) //product name
                ->setWeight($item->weightpacked)
                ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
                ->setTaxClassId(0) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
                ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
                //->setManufacturer() //manufacturer id
                //->setColor(24)
                //->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
                //->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
                //->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
                ->setPrice($item->OnlineUnitPriceInclVAT) //price in form 11.22
                //->setCost($item-22.33) //price in form 11.22
                ->setSpecialPrice($item->OnlineDisountedPriceInclVAT) //special price in form 11.22
                //->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
                //->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
                //->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
                //->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
                //->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
                ->setMetaTitle($item->description)
                ->setMetaKeyword($item->description)
                ->setMetaDescription($item->description)
                ->setDescription($item->description)
                ->setShortDescription($item->description)
                ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
                ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/catalog/product/1/0/' . $item->No_ . '.jpg', array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false) //assigning image, thumb and small image to media gallery
                ->setStockData(array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                    'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                    'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    //'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                    'qty' => $item->inventory//qty
                        )
                )
                ->setBrands($brandid)
                ->setCategoryIds($categoryids); //assign product to categories
        $productModel->save();
```

Comment: the only thing I can see from your code that is using Date is `setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))`, maybe check if that output is the same format at in your database for date fields.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Below is the solution of this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Thank you [Anja](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/21389/anja)
I have looked into the database and the date format was Y-m-d h:i:s, though I am saving the date as an STR TO TIME,

once the above is fixed I found a new Problem related to the Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated, due to the use of Magento 1.9 and PHP VERSION higher than 5.6.

the second problem was fixed using the following PATCH
https://gist.github.com/renttek/29beaaa1e90909639501

:)

Comment: glad I could help :)